# True answers in df

Tags: pandas

We ask in df: "Do you sleep more than 8 hours?"

We want to take only "yes" answers:

```
sleep8 = data["sleep"]
yes = sleep8 == 'yes'
print(yes)
0      False
1      False
2      False
3      False
4      False
   ...  
390    False
391    False
392    False
393    False
394    False
```

Then I need to take only True answers.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`data[data['sleep'] == 'yes']`